# Setting up a Picker in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipickerview, picker

i am trying to create a picker so that the user can select there title (mr/mrs etc) however i keep getting 2 errors

1: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

2: Definition conflicts with previous value

the first is in the class viewcontoller line (line 2). the second error is in the titlepicker function at the end of the code
i have search online and could find anyway to fix these

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource //first error here
{
@IBOutlet weak var titlepicker: UIPickerView!

var titlepickerdata : [String] = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //connect data
    self.titlepicker.delegate = self
    self.titlepicker.dataSource = self
    //input data into the array
    titlepickerdata = ["Mr","Ms","Mrs","Miss","Other"]
    // The number of columns of data
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(titlepicker: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(titlepicker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return titlepickerdata.count
    }

    // The data to return for the row and column that's being passed in
    func pickerView(titlepicker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? // second error returned here
    {
        return titlepickerdata[row]
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Your updated code is still incorrect for exactly the same reasons it was incorrect before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put the definitions of `numberOfComponentsInPickerView`, `pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)`, and `titlepicker(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)` **inside** the definition of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Swift supports nested functions, so this is legal syntax. However, because they are defined inside `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, those functions are not instance methods so they don't meet the requirements of the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol.

It is much easier to see this sort of problem if you indent your code properly. Then those three functions are indented an extra level, showing that they are nested inside `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. You can fix the indentation of the entire file using the menu option Edit > Select All (default shortcut: <kbd>⌘A</kbd>), and then menu option Editor > Structure > Re-Indent (default shortcut: <kbd>⌃`I`</kbd>).

Also, after you move the definitions outside of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, you will need to rename `titlepicker(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)` to `pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)` if you want it to be used as part of the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol.

#### UPDATE

OK, now you have taken the three functions out of `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and put them in `viewDidLoad`, which is wrong for exactly the same reasons. Those functions need to be on the same level as `viewDidLoad` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd error is because, last three functions, e.g. `numberOfComponentsInPickerView`, are miss-placed in the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` function.

The 1st error is therefore there, since `XCode` cannot find the "required" functions of the `UIPickerViewDataSource`

Comment: i have moved the 3 function and it has fixed the second error however it is still providing the same first error

Comment: Edit your question to include the new version of your code.